# How do I annotate a hibernate OneToMany relationship to a table with a compound id?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, one-to-many, compound-key

I am trying to create a OneToMany relationship between two tables where the destination table has a compound id.  One column of the compound id is the one I want to key to, yet I can't figure it out. Example tables:

```
TABLE EXCHANGE_RATE (
    CURRENCY_ID bigint(20),
    YEAR bigint(20),
    RATE float(13,4));

TABLE PRICE (
    PRICE_ID bigint(20),
    CURRENCY_ID bigint(20),
    VALUE float(13,4));
```

The EXCHANGE_RATE table has multiple rows with a given CURRENCY_ID, but the combination of CURRENCY_ID and YEAR is always unique. So I've defined a compound id on EXCHANGE_RATE that includes CURRENCY_ID and YEAR.

However the fk in the PRICE table, CURRENCY_ID, only maps to the CURRENCY_ID column of the EXCHANGE_RATE table.  I've tried everything I can think of to map the PRICE object to an EXCHANGE_RATE object and can't it right. Here is an example of my annotations in the Price.java class:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CURRENCY_ID", 
    referencedColumnName = "CURRENCY_ID", 
    insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Set<ExchangeRate> getExchangeRates() {
    return this.exchangeRates;
}
```

I've also tried the following annotations:

leaving out referencedColumnName:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CURRENCY_ID", insertable = false, 
updatable = false)
```

using referencedColumnName with ID_ prepended:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CURRENCY_ID", referencedColumnName = 
"ID_CURRENCY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

using referencedColumnName with ID. prepended:

```
@JoinColumn(name = "CURRENCY_ID", referencedColumnName =     
"ID.CURRENCY_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

Does anybody know how to make this work? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried using `mappedBy`?

Comment: I got this working. I'll post the answer as soon as i get some time to type it up.